# Edit specific row and column of NSTableView programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I want to press a button, and have a specific box in my NSTableView change its value to something else. Is that possible? How can I do this?

Comment: How are you providing the content of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the model.

That is, get the object you want to change from your array controller, and then modify its attributes.

If you're using a binding, the table will automatically reload the changed cell. If you're using the table view data source methods, just ask the table view to reload the changed cell using `-reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:`.

Comment: More specifically, how do I get an object's contents and modify them?

Comment: Something like this: `[[[myArrayController arrangedObjects] objectAtIndex:row] setSomeAttribute:@"some text"]`